# PIG REGEX_EXTRACT ALL function -> no results

Tags: apache-pig

I have been encountering an issue for several hours already. I have a .csv file with JSON strings inside. Every column in that .csv contains a string with several JSON objects. I imported several columns into PigStorage. Worked so far. Then I tried to extract the JSON objects which have the following form:

> [{"tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00","Value":0,"Quality":1},{"tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.02","Value":10,"Quality":4},{"tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.04","Value":17,"Quality":9},{"tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.06","Value":75,"Quality":6},{"tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.08","Value":63,"Quality":9}];

This is one column.

The `Regex_Extract_All` function does not work woth the following lines of code. Does anyone have an idea on that? I receive always empty results. Here is my code :

```
 A = LOAD '/user/hue/test.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (timestamp, mv1, mv2,mv3,mv4,mv5); --using five columns
 B= foreach A generate mv1,mv2,mv3,mv4,mv5; --removing the timestamp in the first column, not needed anymore
 C= foreach B generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0, '(\\{[^{]*\\})')AS (T:tuple(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5));
```

If I use only one column instead of $0, it does not work as well.

Any help or explanation is very welcome.

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Could you please give an example or the expected result on your example ?

Comment: At the end there should be a table with four columns the timestamp, value, quality and the columnname of the input table. But with this Statement I tired to have a table with one column of all the objects in all of the sourcecloumns. Like this: ("tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.08","Value":63,"Quality":9),("tmestmp":"2014-05-14T07:01:00.02","Value":10,"Quality":4)...Thought the REGEXEXTRACT_ALL command would do that.

Comment: Interesting, I can't make it work either. I'll keep an eye on it and try to make it work. FWIW, `REGEX_EXTRACT` worked with your regex, also only returning one string. You may want to use it as a work around (in a UDF, maybe ?).

Comment: What do you mean by *If I use only one column instead of $0*?

Comment: @winnienickluas: When I put $0 into the Rexgex_extract_all function, it should consider all cells in each row right? It is also not working when I focus one column only.

Comment: @fxm I guess its not possible, to loop through a regex_extract isn't it? So I suppose the UDF might be the way I have to go. Do you have any clue why the Regex_extract_all is not working at all?

Comment: I'm affraid it is. Regarding `regex_extract_all`, it is a mystery. I'll keep digging and inform you if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JsonLoader() to read JSON formatted input. You can use JSsonLoader() instead of using the REGEX and it is very easy to use. Refer `http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig/` for more Info.

Comment: Thanks, but I my case I use csv files with json objects and not json files. Do you think it will still work?