# Getting Blank parenthesis as output while parsing Apache logs using PIG REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

here is the input log sample

```
 122.161.182.200    - Joe [21/Jul/2009:13:14:17 -0700] "GET /rss.pl HTTP/1.1" 
 200 35942 "-" "IE/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; 
 Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; 
 .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; 
 OfficeLivePatch.1.3; MSOffice 12)"
```

And the Pig script is

```
raw_logs = LOAD 'apacheLog.log' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);
logs_base = FOREACH raw_logs GENERATE FLATTEN (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL
(line,'^([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" 
(\\d{3}) (\\d+)"([^"]+)" "([^"]+)"') ) AS (remoteAddr: chararray, 
remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray,  time:
chararray, request: chararray, status: int, bytes_string: chararray,
referrer: chararray, browser: chararray);
dump logs_base;
```

When I dump logs_base getting blank parenthesis as ouput

OUTPUT
    () 
    ()
    ()
    ()

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably your regex does not match the line. I'd try with some regex tool first

Comment: possible duplicate of [PIG REGEX\_EXTRACT ALL function -> no results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774574/pig-regex-extract-all-function-no-results)

Comment: Answer which is pointed out is not related to this question.The question is all about regex with logs not related to JSON.